# c++: how to create unsigned char from UTF-8 code point

Tags: c++, utf-8, char, unsigned

I'm working with a C++ library, and need to create an unsigned char from a UTF-8 code point. For example, if the code point is [decimal 610](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=610&mode=decimal) (a 'latin letter small capital G'), how would I create this in C++?

I javascript, I can do the following:

```js
var temp = String.fromCharCode(610);
console.log(temp); // Outputs a small 'G' (correct)
var codePoint = temp.charCodeAt(0);
console.log(codePoint); // Outputs 610 (correct)
```

In C++ have tried:

```cpp
unsigned char temp = (unsigned char)610;
// compiles, but
Debug::WriteLine((int)temp); // outputs 98 (??)
```

Please provide a code example in C++ which performs the same as the javascript example above.

The environment is in managed C++, but I want to avoid using CLR types as I'm interfacing with a 3rd party library.

Comment: What is the type of `Debug`?  Does `Debug` recognize UTF?  Because C++ ostreams don't.  You need a library to do much with UTF, especially UTF8.

Comment: `unsigned char` is only guaranteed to hold values up to 255; a Unicode codepoint can be much bigger. Your problem is not well stated.

Comment: Ah, life would be so much easier if it was possible to do this.....

Comment: There is no such thing as a UTF-8 code point, do you mean a UTF-8 code unit or a Unicode code point?

Comment: Debug::WriteLine looks like .NET...seems to be C++/CLI!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `unsigned char` is to small to hold a value of 610 (assuming a char is 8 bits wide, it can only hold values from 0 to 255), so it will [wrap around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)*

Use `char16_t` to store a 16-bit char (or `char32_t` for a 32-bit char, which UTF-8 requires).

```
char32_t temp = (char32_t)610;
Debug::WriteLine(temp); // outputs 610 (!!)
```

If you want to handle UTF-8 **strings**, use UTF-8 string literals:

```
u8"I'm a UTF-8 string."
```

---

*It will wrap around even twice in your example:

> 610 - 256 - 256 = 98

Comment: Note that `char16_t` and `char32_t` are being used here as _codepoints_.

Comment: @MooingDuck, you forgot to mention that `char16_t` is not sufficiently large to hold every codepoint and should be avoided for that purpose. A string of `char16_t` may be used to hold UTF-16 as required by Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode code points may need 32 bit representations. In most western languages, 16 bits are enough, but to handle all possible Unicode code points, you really do need 32 bits.

```
uint32_t codePoint = someString.CodePointAt(x);
```

You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point.

Comment: Unicode uses up to 21 bits. There are no numeric data types that can represent 17-31 bits of data, so you need a 32-bit numeric type just to represent 21 bits of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to create an unsigned char pointing to the UTF-8 representation of the Unicode code point 610 you could do:

```
char unsigned temp[] = { 0xc9, 0xa2 };
```